# String to sha1, then to hexadecimal (length 40)

Tags: php, hash, hex, sha1

I want a string to sha1 encoding, then to hex, with a length of 40 characters. This is a Java webservice and the client side is to be done with PHP.

Original code is Java (I don't have the source, only the documentation) and it hashes the following string:

chNFe=43120910585504000174650010000000541123456781&nVersao=100&tpAmb=2&
dhEmi=323031322d30392d32375431363a32303a33342d30333a3030&vNF=1000.00&vICMS=180.00&digVal=37327151612b623074616f514f3966414a7766646c5875715176383d&cIdToken=0000011058550420130001

To the following hex: 
3FACB55248244D98C658FC8A826413BCEF10A4AE

The example above is from the webservice documentation and it says string was encoded with sha1, then the result was encoded to hex.

I tried sha1 then dechex and many other ways, but cannot get the same result. Has anyone an idea of what type of encoding PHP have to do to get this hash?

Thank you.

Comment: The SHA1 of your string above is `48A61A7D2DD56F8A2D301B5EC99152A3BA857C17`. When their doc says "encoded with SHA1, then encoded to hex", it's actually what PHP's `sha1()` function does by default. There are not several ways to calculate an SHA1, so either their doc is wrong, or you've made a mistake copying the string to hash. Have you checked that they're not adding some kind of "salt" to the input? A salt is a string that you either append or prepend to the string before hashing, and that the two ends agree on for extra security.

Comment: @Benjamin There are 2 ways to calculate SHA1: http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips180-3/fips180-3_final.pdf section 6.1

Comment: @calccrypto Can you expand on this? I don't have the time nor the knowledge to read through this document, but I'd definitely be interested in knowing more about that. To me, there's just one SHA1 outcome possible given a binary string.

Comment: @Benjamin They are 2 different algorithms to get the same hash values. The second one just uses less memory

Comment: @calccrypto Thanks for the precision. So let's reformulate: SHA1 is deterministic, and there are no two different possible hashes for a given string.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to follow this: http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=jKHRw%20g4V%20E= . I can't get either of their SHA1 examples to work. Their documentation might be wrong. Is there anything helpful in here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/nfephp/qT9pun7_eDU

Answer (score 0):

The NFE manual is wrong. The example String has a white space at the end of string..

where appears 
5176383d&cIdToken=000001105855042013000 is really 
5176383d &cIdToken=000001105855042013000

Convencional functions the cript this using sha1 resolves the problem ;)

in mysql you can do :
sha1(yourExampleString)...
in php could have the something like...